# How to design the aggregate root?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, entity, aggregateroot

I want to refactor my project with DDD. There are three object, such as bankcard, channel and user. There relation as follows:

1. A bankcard can sign a contract with multi channel.
2. A user can bind multi bankcards.
3. A bankcard can be bound to multi users.

Now the project has three tables, such as bankcard table, bankcards and channels contract table, bankcards and users relationship table.
I want to design bankcard as entity, user and channel as value object(user entity and channel entity be maintained at other domain).
So how should I design the aggregate root. Consider bankcard as aggregate and the channel list, user list as aggregate root's property, or design bankcard, bankcard-sign-contract, bankcard-user-relationship as aggregate root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one Entity (*bankcard*) and two Value Objects, I'd say that it sounds natural to model the Entity as the Aggregate Root and the two Value Objects as properties of it.

Comment: Thank your answer.I need to handle the user's binding status (such as pre-binding, has bound, Unbundling), and the same as channel's sign status. So how to show these status in Aggregate Root?